# Display array items(json) using For Loop, If Statement and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, ionic-framework

I am trying to filter through two JSON array objects in order to display selected results from the arrays. I am using two For Loops and an If Statement to filter out what needs to be shown.

However my issue comes in that the If Statement does not seem to filter out the results of the For Loop. Every item in the JSON object is displayed. Please help.

**angular/javascript**

```
      var url = generateQuery('GET', '/products', CONFIG, params);
      $scope.result = "";
      var i;
      var j;
      $scope.items = [];
      $http.get(url)
          .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.result = data;

              for (i = 0; i < $scope.result.products.length; i++) {

                  for (j = 0; j < $scope.result.products[i].categories.length; j++) {
                      $scope.category_limit = $scope.result.products[i].categories[j];

                      if ($scope.category_limit = 'Jewellery') {

                          $scope.items.push({
                              image: $scope.result.products[i].featured_src,
                              name: $scope.result.products[i].title,
                              price: '$' + $scope.result.products[i].price + ' (R' + ($scope.result.products[i].price * $scope.convert.results.rate.Rate).toFixed(2) + ')',
                              id: $scope.result.products[i].id,
                              cat: $scope.category_limit
                          });
                          $ionicLoading.hide();

                      } else {
                          $ionicLoading.hide();
                      }
                  }

              }

          })
```

**html**

```
        <div class="category-col" ng-repeat="i in items" id="swap_row_col">

            <a ng-href="#/app/products/{{i.id}}" href="#/app/products/{{i.id}}" class="no-underline">
                <img src= {{i.image}} class="category-image-col">      
                <!--<img src='images/add_to_cart.png' style="height: 24px; width: 28px; z-index: 5; position: fixed; margin-left: 34%; margin-top: -13%;">                                         -->
                <div class="category-name-col"> {{i.name}} </div>
                <div class="category-price-col"> {{i.price}} </div>
                <div class="category-price-col"> {{i.cat}} </div>
            </a>

        </div>
```

Comment: Can you give some details on what the returned `data` looks like?

Comment: Could it be that "Jewellery" is supposed to be "Jewelry"?  Without seeing your data, we are just guessing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think your missing the == sign 
 if ($scope.category_limit == 'Jewellery'){
.....
}

Comment: Okay it seems that the data objects I was receiving was the issue. Each Products object did not have the same amount of category items. $scope.category_limit == 'Jewellery' is correct though, thanks. I will mark this as the correct answer as it will solve related issues